# How to return mapped data to DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Wondering if anyone can help me with this code, I know it's pretty simple stuff I just can't seem to get it working

I have some data that's being mapped over and calling a function to show the data, what can I change in the function to have a new li created for each member

Comment: Use `forEach()` if you're not returning anything from the mapped function.

Comment: What is `selectors.staffList`, is it ul element already sitting in DOM?

Comment: @raina77ow Just updated the code to make a bit clearer, that is a ul element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be setting the `innerHTML` of `li`, not `textContent`.

Also, you're creating an `<li>` in both `showStaffMembers()` and `getMemberTemplate()`. You should do it in just one of them.

If `getMemberTemplate()` returns the entire `<li>`, you don't need to create an element in `showStaffMembers()`. Just append the `<li>` to the end of the `staffList`.

```js
const showStaffMembers = (member) => {
  const li = getMemberTemplate(member);
  selectors.staffList.insertAdjacentHTML(li, 'beforeend');
}

// Load the staff members from the data
const loadStaffMembers = () => {
  staffMembers.forEach(showStaffMembers);
}

// Return the HTML markup for a staff member
const getMemberTemplate = member => {
  return `
    <li class="staff-member" style="display:flex; align-items:center;">
      <img src=${member.img} alt=${member.name} />
      <p>${member.name}</p>
      <p>${member.occupation}</p>
      <p>${member.team}</p>
    </li>
  `
}
```